# When and how are one-letter edits absolutely necessary?

Tags: soporte, ediciones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making minor spelling, grammar, or punctuation edits](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137/making-minor-spelling-grammar-or-punctuation-edits)

When editing a question, it says: *Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary*
But then I'm not allowed to make a one letter edit, so how can I specify that a circumstance is *absolutely necessary* ?

It is *not* a trivial change, though, because this is a site about a language and one letter mistakes can turn a question's assumption wrong, producing useless answers.

Comment: I agree with you, in spirit.  However, it's a limitation we must live with.  See [this answer of mine](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/141/12) for some suggestions on how to work around the limitation.